# RSA 1024 bit forge a new matching signature from a chosen message

Tags: rsa, public-key, signature, attack

I have an RSA signature scheme with 1024-bit key where I know the following:

- Public modulus $N$
- Public exponent $e=3$
- A lot of signatures

**Summary:**

To compute a signature, an MD5 hash is calculated from a collection of byte and the textbook RSA private key function is applied to that. The verification procedure for a signature $S$ is to check that $S^e\bmod N$ is the MD5 hash of the alleged message.

Our teacher give us more than one signature.

**Question:**

Can someone give advice to find a practical way to find a new matching signature from a chosen message?

Comment: "one of several working private exponent $d$", what does this mean?

Comment: There is no known way to recover $d = 3^{-1} \bmod lcm(P-1, Q-1)$ given access to an oracle that computes $f(x) = x^d \bmod N$.  Are you sure that your teacher didn't ask you to compute the signature for another message that you haven't been given the signature to?

Comment: Yes, the goal is to compute the signature of a message chosen by us. My teacher told us that having many signature there are possibility to find a new matching signature from a chosen message.

Comment: Attempting to recover $d$ is a deadend.  Instead, you should attempt to figure out how to deduce a signature without knowing $d$.  Hint: the relation $a^d \times b^d = (ab)^d \pmod N$ is useful.

Comment: @poncho Can you give more detail please? I understand your hint but not how to deal with results.

Comment: @fgrieu Question edited. I don't understand why factor many hash and find common factor can help me to forge a signature from a **chosen** message. Can someone make a simple example to clarify please? This is my first year in the cryptography course and i want to understand fully. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The message is chosen by the forging procedure itself, not the person who's using that procedure. $\hspace{.4 in}$

Comment: Check out '4.1 Coppersmith's theorem' in [Boneh's Twenty Years of Attacks on the RSA Cryptosystem](https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/papers/RSA-survey.pdf)

Comment: @fgrieu The signature for the message **M is simply MD5(M)d mod N** as previous questions. I have many signatures with their messages. Hope this can help you to better understand.

Comment: Again, this [answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/29089/555) will help. More precisely, the problem is that in section 3 of [this paper](http://www.jscoron.fr/publications/iso9796-1.pdf#page=3), with $\mu=\text{MD5}$, and restriction to messages $m_i$ (per the notation of step 3) that the adversary can not choose, but rather receives (thus replacing "ask for the signature of the $m_i$" in step 4 by "using the known signatures of the $m_i$").

Comment: The problem (with all messages chosen) is also considered in section 2 of that [paper](http://www.jscoron.fr/publications/padding.pdf#page=3). Notice that nowadays we know how to make $\text{MD5}$ collisions, thus the only case of interest is when the message for which signature is known are not chosen by the adversary, but rather given/intercepted; that makes the attack slightly more complex.

Comment: @fgrieu : The problem with this [answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/29089/555) is that i don't understand how to implement it. Why computing S = (M)3 mod N of some messages can help (the produced signature will not be valid)?. Factoring hashes will produce a set of factor, as i understand i can then forge a valid signature only if the message that i will hash can be represented by a sequence of previously founded factors. This will not give the freedom to sign a choosen message. Am i wrong?

Comment: @Seed3Key: you are right that you will not be able to sign _any message that you may choose_; but you will be able to sign _some message that you choose_ and is not one of those that you have been given. The later is the meaning of _chosen message_ in cryptography, at least in the context of digital signatures. If the verification procedure checks $\left(S^e\bmod N\right)=\text{MD5}(M)$ that's the best attack I see.

Comment: @fgrieu Yes the verification process is ((S)e mod N) = MD5(M). So basically i need to factor all the hashes of the signature that my teacher gives and find linear combination. Then i need to try to mod the message that i want to forge to produce an hash that can be represented by factors previously founded. Do you think that i can a little bit control the output of the MD5 hash in order to have more probability? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30018/discussion-between-seed3key-and-fgrieu).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We assume an RSA signature scheme with appendix where the signature of message $M$ is $S=\left(\operatorname{MD5}(M)\right)^d\bmod N$, and the verification procedure checks that $0\le S<N$ and $\left(S^e\bmod N\right)=\operatorname{MD5}(M)$, with $e=3$ (or other relatively small odd $e\ge3$). Eve somewhat got $k$ rightful signatures $S_i$ and perhaps the corresponding messages $M_i$ (which Eve could not influence). Eve wants to construct another $M$, and matching signature $S$.

---

Eve will make a multiplicative forgery: she'll find a message $M$ and a matching set of $k$ non-negative integers $e_i$, such that $\operatorname{MD5}(M)\cdot\prod\left(\operatorname{MD5}(M_i)\right)^{e_i}$ is an $e$<sup>th</sup> power, then compute the signature of $M$ as
$$S=\left(\sqrt[e]{\operatorname{MD5}(M)\cdot\prod\left(\operatorname{MD5}(M_i)\right)^{e_i}}\right)\cdot\left(\prod S_i^{e_i}\right)^{-1}\bmod N$$
which verifies $\left(S^e\bmod N\right)=\operatorname{MD5}(M)$.

Define $m_{i,j}$ as the [multiplicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicity_%28mathematics%29#Multiplicity_of_a_prime_factor) of prime $p_j$ in the factorization of $\operatorname{MD5}(M_i)$, and define $m_j$ as the multiplicity of prime $p_j$ in the factorization of $\operatorname{MD5}(M)$. The goal of Alice is that $\forall j,\; m_j+\sum_i m_{i,j}\cdot e_i\equiv0\pmod e$. That linear system of equation with unknowns $e_i$ is equivalent to $\operatorname{MD5}(M)\cdot\prod\left(\operatorname{MD5}(M_i)\right)^{e_i}$ being an $e$<sup>th</sup> power.

Eve computes the hashes $H_i=\operatorname{MD5}(M_i)$, directly or as $S_i^e\bmod N$. She factors the $H_i$ at least partially (with $H_i<2^{128}$, even complete factorization is feasible). She can ignore any $H_i$ with a prime factor $p_j$ not appearing in the other $H_i$ [and $m_{i,j}\not\equiv0\pmod e$, but that is likely for $k$ large enough to carry the attack]; in particular she can without loosing much ignore those $H_i$ with a prime factor larger than about $k^3/\log(k)$, which are unlikely to be of any help.

Outline of the rest: Eve repeatedly

- selects a message $M$ of her choice [that she did not previously select, and distinct from the $M_i$ if these are given]
- computes $\operatorname{MD5}(M)$ and factors it at least partially
- if that factorization consists entirely of primes occurring in the factorization of at least one of the $H_i$ kept [in that screening Eve could exclude primes with multiplicity $m_j\equiv0\pmod e$ in the factorization of $\operatorname{MD5}(M)$, and occurrences with multiplicity $m_{i,j}\equiv0\pmod e$ in the $H_i$, but that won't make much of a difference for $k$ large enough to carry the attack]

  - attempts to solve the linear system, and if that works

    - computes $S$, noting that the $e$<sup>th</sup> root extraction reduces to dividing the exponents by $e$ in the known factorization of $\operatorname{MD5}(M)\cdot\prod\left(\operatorname{MD5}(M_i)\right)^{e_i}$
    - outputs $M$ and $S$.

It will help to have preprocessed the system of linear equations. For larger $k$, solving the linear system will succeed for a large proportion of $M$ having passed the screening; or/and it will be possible to put an upper bound of the $p_j$ early on, making the factorization easier and the linear system smaller, thus easier to manage.

A small $e$ helps the attack, but with a large-enough $k$ it can be carried for any $e$. The size of the public modulus $N$ of the RSA key is essentially immaterial; what matters most is the width of the hash, which at 128-bit is grossly insufficient.

---

A slightly simpler variant of the problem (where all the messages are chosen, which is moot for a hash without collision resistance as $\operatorname{MD5}$ is nowadays) is discussed by Jean-Sébastien Coron, David Naccache and Julien P. Stern in section 2 of: [*On the Security of RSA Padding*](http://www.jscoron.fr/publications/padding.pdf#page=3) (in [proceedings of Crypto 1999](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-48405-1_1)); or, when we set $\mu$ to $\operatorname{MD5}$, by Don Coppersmith, Jean-Sébastien Coron, François Grieu, Shai Halevi, Charanjit Jutla, David Naccache, and Julien P. Stern in section 3 of: [*Cryptanalysis of ISO/IEC 9796-1*](http://www.jscoron.fr/publications/iso9796-1.pdf#page=3http://www.jscoron.fr/publications/iso9796-1.pdf#page=3) (in [Journal of Cryptology, 2008](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00145-007-9007-5)). The idea of a building coefficients by solving a linear system based on prime multiplicity was introduced by Yvo Desmedt and Andrew M. Odlyzko in [*A chosen text attack on the RSA cryptosystem and some discrete logarithm schemes*](http://www.dtc.umn.edu/~odlyzko/doc/arch/rsa.attack.pdf) (in [proceedings of Crypto 1985](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-39799-X_40)).

Comment: I need to read it many times before understand it fully (hopefully) but is the accepted answer.